# uilabel disappears when being applied rotation on it

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

what I am having is

```
 UIView
     1.Image1
     2.Image2
     3.UILabel
```

like an image below

[image]

Then I apply rotation on UILabel by doing

```
- (void)viewDidLoad    
    {
        testLabel.transform     =   CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0.25);
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

and when I am running the application, the uilabe is disppearing after all. Look at the second image for your reference

[image]

Please point out what I am doing wrong here....and how to get the work done

Thanks

Comment: Does the label appears without the rotation ?

Comment: yes it does without rotation and then after applying the rotation, it is gone

Comment: Maybe you can just set a colored background to the label to see if this is a render issue with the text or if all the label is hidden.

Comment: I tried the same. It worked on mine. Have you hooked up the label with the view controller? Some suggestions. Try loading the text with a different value in viewDidLoad. Does the changed text appear? Also the above suggestion by iSofTom looks relevant. Try and see what happens

Comment: when I tried to multiply  M_PI by .2, it works. In general, if the factor is .x0 ( such as .2,.3,.4), all work. I am wondering why

Comment: then try to cast float on the returned value

Answer (score 2):

Watch out because Autolayout cause a lot of problems.

Try to deselect 'Use Autolayout'

It solves to me all the problems trying to translate objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try multiplying by a smaller value against PI to see if it is rotating or just disappearing. If I remember correctly, rotations are not based on the center, but on the top-left corner, so you have to translate afterwards!

For instance, to rotate a video clip this is what I had to do:

```
CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
CGAffineTransform translateToCenter = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(640, 480);
CGAffineTransform mixedTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotation, translateToCenter);
[firstTrackInstruction setTransform:mixedTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

I rotated by PI first (180 degrees), but because the center of rotation is the top left corner, my video clip was now in the opposite quadrant, and needed to be transformed back! This may be what is happening with your label.

So try this, assuming your label is 42x21 dimensions..

```
CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
CGAffineTransform translateToCenter = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(42, 21);
CGAffineTransform mixedTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotation, translateToCenter);
label.transform = mixedTransform;
```

Comment: about the transform property : Specifies the transform applied to the receiver, relative to the center of its bounds.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the [super viewDidLoad] first :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad    
{
[super viewDidLoad];        
testLabel.transform     =   CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0.25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoLayout and AutoResizing often cause difficulties when you apply transforms as these seem to alter the frame rather than the bounds and center of a view. Hence the automatic adjustments wreck havoc on your layout. Try to wrap the transformed label in a view that does not change dimensions and layout that view within its superview however you want.